# How to put args in a onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Many people have already answered this question however, in my case it's a little bit tricky.

I have 4 different place to put returned data from my ajax from 4 different files.

I am looking for a code like this :

```js
function httpBB(file,id){
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = loadTicket(id);
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'assets/php/'+file+'.php');
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

file represent the file received by ajax and id represent the id of the div in my html.

Thanks for the help

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find this way

not the better one but it works.

```js
function httpBB(file){
    switch (file) {
        case 'ticket_new':
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = loadTicketNew;
            break;
        case 'ticket_my':
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = loadTicketMy;
            break;
        case 'ticket_current':
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = loadTicketCurr;
            break;
        case 'ticket_all':
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = loadTicketAll;
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'assets/php/'+file+'.php');
    httpRequest.send();
}

function loadTicketNew(){
    loadTicket('new')
}

function loadTicketMy(){
    loadTicket('my')
}

function loadTicketCurr(){
    loadTicket('new')
}

function loadTicketAll(){
    loadTicket('my')
}
```

If someone find something better than this solution, thanks, but for now I will tuse this sh**

Have a nice day